# Edit text scroll bar issue in Constraint layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to show scroll bar in my edit text only when height of my edit text reach at the end of my layout height. That's working fine if i am entering/adding blank space but its causing problem when I my text reaches to end of my edit text width. Once my text reaches to end of my edit text width it start showing me scroll bar whereas it should show up when i reach to (height)end of screen.

Please advice how can i resolve this issue. Please find attached image and code for reference.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFeedback"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Some text"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSend"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierEnd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editFeedback" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="This is a footer"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrierEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="Footer" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please state what version of ConstraintLayout you’re using.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this with the standard EditText. You say you want vertical bars, but only when the edit text is reaches “X” size, so you will have to measure your Edit Text and only enable the scrollbars programmatically when you reach certain threshold.

Comment: When you say "it's showing the scrollbar when text reaches width of EditText" you are assuming that this is not the first line of your EditText but your last line correct? Meaning, EditText' text is at last line as far as height?

Comment: @Martin Marconcini  we are using constrain layout version 1.1.0 in our project.can share your code.

Comment: @RedM yes i know but i need the edit text to show scroll bar when it reaches to the bottom it can show show the scroll bar and weird thing is that i can't select any text from the EditText.

Answer (score 2):

This might help I have edited a few things in the code. I have removed the barrier and changed it with a horizontal guideline and set that guideline to 80% of the screen height and the footer object aligned to that horizontal guideline. Kindly look the code below I hope it solves your problem. If you have any doubt about how I set the constraints I'll be happy to help.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFeedback"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Some text"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editFeedback"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00999999" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="This is a footer"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And also here is the image of how now the layout looks.
[image: Layout]

Comment: When I tried it, scrollbars appear only when the height of edit Text is just above the footer. And also can you show an elaborated picture of the problem like for eg. with the text that you actually like to be shown in that particular way. It would be very helpful

Comment: yes it will work perfectly when you hit enter for new line but on normal typing without hitting enter it will show the scroll bar after the minimum editText height is reached

Comment: @Jinu that is the nature of the EditText, if you need a custom behavior, you’ll have to write your own/extend/delegate as much as you can.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini it's working perfectly on other layouts so i have raised a bug for this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80393448

Answer (score 2):

Its work my side Please check at your side may be its.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFeedback"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Some text"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSend"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierEnd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editFeedback" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="This is a footer"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrierEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="Footer" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it could be achieve programatically.

Disabling the vertical scroll bar when text reaches the last character of the line will do the trick.  `editText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);`. Also, after the text is back at the next line, the scroll bar can be set again to true `editText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);`

I good start could be implementing interfaces like `TextWatcher` and `EditText.OnScrollChangeListener` and using them both while enabling/disabling scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft) . If you do not specify  `windowSoftInputMode` in manifest then it will be default as `stateUnspecified` or `adjustUnspecified`.

Right now your `EditText` is being resize when softkeyboard opens . Try to add a `windowSoftInputMode` to avoid resizing or put the layout in `ScrollView`(In case if you want whole layout to be visible during soft keyboard open).

you can specify `adjustNothing` flag. It will prevent the resize.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        >
    </activity>
```